# Firefox addon development using JetBrains WebStorm. What to do with numerous warnings?

Tags: firefox-addon, phpstorm, webstorm, firefox-developer-tools

I am developing a firefox addon now. I have tried a lot of IDEs for JavaScript and finally ended up with JetBrains WebStorm.
But when I opened my project(about 1000 lines) in WebStorm the first time it showed me about 500 warnings. The most of the warnings are "Unresolved function or method" and "Unresolved variable or type".

For example this 2 lines contain 4 warnings:

```
let sss = Cc["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);
```

1. getService (Unresolved function or method)
2. nsIStyleSheetService (Unresolved variable)
3. loadAndRegisterSheet (Unresolved function or method)
4. AUTHOR_SHEET (Unresolved variable)

For now I just disabled all this warnings. But maybe it's not the best way to handle the problem? There are "libraries" in WebStorm for jQuery, Ext JS, Prototype, Dojo and other. And a custom JavaScript library can be added. Is there a way to add/create such a custom library? Or is there another way to handle all this warning not disabling them at all?

P.S. There's Komodo IDE that provides such autocompletions:
[image: Komodo IDE]

and I thought that maybe someone extracted it from Komodo IDE and added to WebStorm as a library.

Comment: I just discovered that WebStrorm inspections understand JSHint-like `/* global MY_GLOBAL */` comment("a directive for telling JSHint about global variables that are defined elsewhere"). It can help a little. But for some reason it doesn't understand `/* exported EXPORTED_LIB */` comment("a directive for telling JSHint about global variables that are defined in the current file but used elsewhere").

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by cloning the [repository](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) and adding the lib/sdk directory as a new library under Settings->Languages & Frameworks->JavaScript->Libraries.

Comment: In my project this reduced the number of warnings from 823 to 587.

Comment: Interesting. Which type of warnings still appears?

Comment: All I need to do to hide all warnings is to uncheck "Unresolved JavaScript function" and "Report undeclared properties as error" (in "Unresolved JavaScript variable") in WebStorm inspections. So if I don't uncheck it I get the same warnings that I mentioned in the question: `Unresolved variable nsISessionStore` and `Unresolved function or method getService` for example. And it doesn't matter whether it's 823 warnings or 587. In any case I have to uncheck this 2 options in order to be able to use WebStorm IDE. And my add-on isn't an Add-on SDK based one. It's a plain bootstrapped add-on.